# Почему люди с "нулевым" рейтингом имеют права задавать вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

*Сразу говорю, я давно не помню систему рейтинга в SO и могу совершить грубые ошибки при написания данного текста. Заранее прошу поправить меня*

В последнее время Stackoverflow переполнен людьми с рейтингом **от 1 до 10**. Такое ощущение, что они создают **однодневные аккаунты**, задают вопросы, забрасывают аккаунты, если у них низкий рейтинг и создают новый.

**Как я понимаю:**
Проблема состоит в том, что этот метод обходит такую важную функцию как "у меня низкий рейтинг - надо выходить из него отвечая на вопросы других". Зачем париться с рейтингом, когда можно создавать новые аккаунты и задавать новые вопросы?

**Чем это плохо:**
(Это не касается нормальных новичков). Сообщество "засоряется" пустыми и ненужными вопросами. В основном такие новички просят решить школьльную задачку не приложив усилия, рассказать как сделать сдвиг в css на 20px и т.д. Вчера, как я понимаю, женщина вообще спрашивала про то, что стоит ее сыну покупать GTA или нет... "Она" только зарегистрировалась, а уже вопрос может задавать. А плохо это тем, что вопросы людей, которым реально нужна помощь с нечастыми проблемами в программировании, теряются в море этого мусора.

**Как я вижу решение:**
Задать порог в 50-100 баллов (5-10 голосов), чтобы человек имел право создавать вопросы только тогда, когда ответит на вопросы других и они его оценят.

Вот один из примеров "новичков" и как на него реагирует сообщество.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так было и будет всегда. При вашей схеме первый вопрос никогда бы не появился, кстати.

Comment: @älёxölüt Это не идеальная схема. Можно опустить кол-во голосов до 30 (допустим).  Посмотрев сейчас на свои достижения: я получил 30 голосов за 2 дня ответив на 2-3 вопроса

Comment: Из серии про бассейн -- *вот научитесь плавать, тогда и дадим воду*

Comment: @avp пусть плавать и умеют. Надо гнать тех, кто в него писает.

Comment: @Antonio112009, если серьезно, то на мой взгляд, основная ценность этого сайта в возможности спросить и **быстро получить квалифицированный ответ**, который можно уточнить, вживую обсудить и т.д. Все остальное нужно только весьма ограниченной группе (вероятно, несколько процентов от всех посетителей)

Comment: Вы ответили на эти 2-3 вопроса за два дня потому, что эти вопросы были, и на них не было дано аналогичных ответов других участников. Ваше предложение снизит поток вопросов в 5-10 раз (судя по вопросам на главной). Это 20 вопросов в сутки. 1-2 вопроса в сутки по метке вроде c#. Оцените свой шанс набрать хотя бы 50 репутации, если вам придётся конкурировать за право ответа с парой десятков отвечающих за 1 вопрос в сутки :)

Comment: @PashaPash я образно имел ввиду 50. Если я не ошибаюсь, то на основном SO такая функция есть. Про конкуренцию - не каждый знает ответ на тот или иной вопрос, а значит у других есть возможность дать на него ответ и заработать рейт. К примеру, я не смогу конкурировать с людьми в c#, linux, python, jQuery, js и т.д., потому что я знаю ответы на другие вопросы. А так же стоит заметить, что 30+ вопросов за 4 часа (сегодня) не имеют ответа. Это шанс заработать репутацию

Comment: окей, а что если ты новичок которому пока не по силам дать качественный ответ на подавляющее большинство вопросов, но у самого вопросов и проблемы тонны?

Comment: @Antonio112009 Нет, на основном SO такой фукции нет. Ну ок, предположим что из этих 30 останется 3. По одному на C#, Python и JS. Вы сможете набрать по ним репутацию? По java будет один неотвеченный вопрос послезавтра. Может быть. А может на следующей неделе. А может и не будет, т.к. сейчас конкуренция за ответы меньше. А т.к. смогут задавать вопросы только те, кто отвечает - то вопросов станет еще меньше, а те что меньше - станут сложнее. И участники вроде вас вообще не получат ни шанса на ответ, ни шанса на вопрос.

Comment: @Antonio112009 в качестве простого примера - примените ваше предложение к себе. У вас нет не одного ответа на мете. Попробуйте набрать на мете хотя бы 5 плюсов за ответы. А потом уже вносите предложения :)

Comment: @PashaPash на мете сложнее набрать, чем в обычном SO:) В SO обычном ответы все "линейные". Есть конкретная проблема и есть конкретный ответ. В моем случае тут - есть проблема и есть две стороны ответа (если не больше)

Comment: Я понимаю, что это не правильно требовать набрать с одной стороны какой-то минимальный порог голосов, но с другой это уменьшает откровенный мусор из ненужных вопросов от новичков.

Comment: Ощущение, что ru.so переполнен вопросами новичков возникает потому, что популярность сайта постепенно растёт. Когда он только открылся, посещаемость была низкая, вопросов, соответственно, тоже было мало. Я помню, раньше больше времени на en.so проводил, потому что тут не на что было отвечать.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что большинство пользователей StackOverflow проходило три этапа:

1. Будущий пользователь ресурса ищет что-то в поисковике, и в выдаче на первых позициях оказывается SO. В итоге он просто находит ответ на интересующий его вопрос (без всяких регистраций) и возвращается к текущей работе. Через некоторое время, после определенного количества удачных находок с помощью поисковика, у него формируется ощущение, что SO - полезный ресурс.
2. На втором этапе будущий пользователь решает пройти регистрацию. Зачем ему это может понадобиться, если ответы на вопросы можно найти и так? Видимо, чтобы выйти за рамки режима read-only и о чем-то спросить/оценить/прокомментировать. Причем как правило, выйти из режима read-only этому человеку нужно "здесь и сейчас", а не когда-нибудь там, в светлом будущем. Иначе зачем ему вообще второй этап, если режим read-only прекрасен и на первом?
3. На третьем этапе человек "втягивается" в процесс и становится полноценным членом сообщества: он отвечает, комментирует, правит, да и просто просиживает на ресурсе целыми днями.

Понятно, что для сообщества ценнее всего те участники, которые дошли до третьего этапа. Но многие ли захотят попадать на него, минуя второй?
Большой ли процент тех, у кого есть реальный вопрос, готовы "прокачивать рейтинг" в ожидании права что-то написать? Или они просто перейдут по следующей ссылке в поисковой выдаче еще на первом этапе? Многие ли будут готовы сразу переходить с первого этапа на третий, или они навсегда останутся на первом? Мне кажется, идти вперед захотят лишь единицы. А значит, **прохождение второго этапа должно быть достаточно доступным**.

Это как добыча золота, когда ради нескольких крупинок нужно промыть тонны грязи. Конечно, можно долго ходить туда-сюда, в надежде сразу найти килограммовый самородок, но будет ли такой способ эффективен? Вряд ли.
Поэтому **мне кажется, что нынешняя система весьма неплоха. Не идеальна, но неплоха. И ломать ее вряд ли стоит**.